# writing unit test using mockito

Tags: mockito

I am writing unit tests in java using mockito.

This is the statement that I am trying to test.

```
final Map<EntityKey, Element<Movie>> resultMap = Watcher.watch(movies);
```

movies is **Set** of movie names which is a key to identify a movie.

I mocked watcher class

```
final Watcher<Movie> watcher = mock(Watcher.class);
```

Mockito.when(watcher.watch(Matchers.any(Set.class))).thenReturn()

what to include in "thenReturn"??

Comment: If you are going to stub the watch method, what behavior are you testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `thenReturn` function you need to pass an object of the same type as the method you are mocking's return type.

When this method is then called on that object, it will return the object you passed to `thenReturn` instead of actually going into the function.

This is the core concept behind mocking.

Having said that. If you are trying to test the Watcher.watch method then you probably don't want to mock it anyway. You should only mock those classes you are NOT testing.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a `Map<EntityKey,Element<Movie>>` that would be suitable for use in the rest of the test.  I'm not quite sure what your test is actually trying to assert, but whatever it is, choose the `Map` accordingly.  Your `Map` object is what you want to return from `thenReturn`.